# Realtime Chart on Android using ChartDroid(or Any)

Tags: android, eclipse, graph, charts

Is there any example to show chart realtime.
My temperature sensor read data real time and send it to DB then use data from DB to build Chart Realtime.

Comment: AchartEngine will help. http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi i'm having the same questions as you and am currently trying to find out more, from what i've cam acrossed I guess you can follow this example over here, http://www.jjoe64.com/p/graphview-library.html and you can probably update the values via a webservice? maybe json or something similar make work for you!